# AMSART: 'page break' between title, TOC, abstract, and 'main matter'

Tags: amsart

In `amsart`, how do you put a 'page break' between title, table of content, abstract, footnotes (date, 'thanks', etc.) and the body of the work (the 'sections')?

Comment: How about poviding a MWE? On weekends writing a MWE from scratch is the last thing most people would like to do. :)

Comment: not tested.  after `\maketitle`, insert `\newpage`.  but some example code would be much more lilely to get a reliable answer.

Comment: @HarishKumar What does MWE mean?

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I put `\newpage` after `\table of contents` and it seems to work. Thanks. Anyway, I'll surely add some sample code  if it can be useful.

Comment: @Ryo -- the problem has been solved for you, but a small compilable file that shows the problem will help the next person who's looking for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\newpage` somewhere after `\maketitle` will start a new page.

in the present case, since the toc is wanted on the first page, the place
to insert `\newpage` is after `\tableofcontents`.